# How to inject non SingletonComponents into Hilt Worker?

Tags: android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

I am trying to inject a repository into a worker. The worker is using the `@HiltWorker` annotation which states that `Only dependencies available in the SingletonComponent can be injected into the Worker.`

So what can I do when the repository is scoped to `@ViewModelComponent`? It seems very limiting to only have singleton injections into the worker, especially when repositories are scoped to viewmodels in a lot of cases.

```kotlin
@HiltWorker
class WorkerGetData @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted val context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParameters: WorkerParameters,
    val firestore: IFirestoreRepository,
    ): CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters) { ... }
```

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class BindFirestore {
    @Binds
    @ViewModelScoped
    abstract fun bindFirestoreRepository(firestoreRepository: FirestoreRepository): IFirestoreRepository
}
```